# How to Edit Content in $content['main']

Tags: drupal-7

I am maintaining a Drupal 7 site that was developed by another developer and I'm trying to
 move the search field on the results page to appear under the H1.  Currently the site has a search field that appears at the very top (above the top navigation) > after the user submits a keyword in the search field, they are taken to the Results page which has a second search field that appears right above the H1.

I know that the second search field on the Results page is within the $content['main'], but I can't seem to locate how to move the search field to save my life!  The script in the template.tpl.php file that contains the $content['main'] is pasted below.  I've checked the MySQL database (field_revision, field_data, & node tables), Structure (Panels, Mini Panels, Views, Pages, & Blocks), and content types -- all to no avail.

```
<?php if (!empty($content['main'])): ?>
<?php print render($content['main']); ?>

<? // debugging  ?>
<pre><?php print_r($node); ?></pre>
<?php
print '<div>var_dump <br/>';
var_dump($content); 
print '</div>';
?>
<? // debugging  ?>
```

Output from debugging script that was pasted below the $content['main']

```
var_dump
array(5) { ["search"]=> string(798) " 

" ["header"]=> string(0) "" ["main"]=> string(4492) "
```

I've looked into this [Drupal Answers post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6787/where-does-drupal-store-the-content-of-a-nodes-body), but haven't found the search field in any of the suggestion yet.

Any insight would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the codes related to this page? Also try to do a `var_dump($content['main']);`.

Comment: Screenshots of the code not from the UI!

Answer (score 0):

> Currently the site has a search field that appears at the very top (above the top navigation)

1) Is this a **block**? If so change the visibility settings of the block or remove it if you prefer.

2) Does this appear in any page? If so go into **page.tpl.php** inside your theme folder and find any code related with 'search'. Then copy here the results.

Comment: Thank u 4 taking the time 2 help me.  Sorry 4 the delay, I've been trying 2 figure this out the past week.  The search field circled in red (http://i199.photobucket.com/albums/aa1/ivanc_1/cc805e75-dbfc-4fbd-826a-85cc2a538f98_zpsa364b940.jpg) is the 2nd search box that appears only on the Results page & the one to remove.  Output w/ var_dump($content['main') (http://i199.photobucket.com/albums/aa1/ivanc_1/ScreenShot2013-08-15at93156AM_zpsab932200.png). It is not a block, nor does it appear on any other pages. I've done many searches, but haven't found where its called. :(

Comment: If it is not a common block then it is printed with codes from **template.php or page.tpl.php or any other module** like described on 2 of my answer.